# Prove that exponent integral uniformly converges

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, convergence-divergence

> Prove that integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x^4}dx$  uniformly
> converges on $E = [\alpha_0; +\infty], \alpha_0 > 0.$

**My thoughts:**

Probably, using the Weierstrass theorem, bounding the original one integral with the fixed constant $\alpha_0 > 0$ one:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha x^4}dx \leq \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha_0 x^4}dx,
$$
where the second one integral converges because:
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-\alpha_0 x^4}dx < \int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x}dx = 1 < \infty.
$$
But is it true for any $x$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{4}\geq x$ if $x \geq 1$. So $e^{-\alpha_0 x^{4}} \leq e^{-\alpha_0 x} $ in this case. [ $\int_1^{\infty} e^{-\alpha_0 x}dx =\frac 1 {\alpha_0} e^{-\alpha_0}<\infty$]. Now split the integral into integral form $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $\infty$. In the first part use the fact that $e^{-\alpha_0 x^{4}} <1$.